# How to select column equal another type of value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables `Hre_Profile` and `Hre_WorkHistory`.
A 2 table join with below script:

```
alter table Hre_Profile  add constraint fk_01 foregin key(ID) references 
Hre_workhistory (ProfileID)
```

The schema of `Hre_Profile` is as follows:

```
Hre_Profile (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER primary key, SupervisorID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, CodeEmp varchar(50))
```

```
ID                                   | SupervisorID | codeemp
D4ABD930-AC52-4F39-B235-0E6CA6C32309 | NULL         |400287
6FE02B7A-09C7-4955-80D7-0FD1A42CDD8B | NULL         |1002
ABC12343-AC52-4F39-B235-0E6CAVCXXCDS | NULL         |10007
```

The schema of `Hre_WorkHistory` is as follows:

```
Hre_WorkHistory (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER primary key, ProfileID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Supervisor varchar(50))
```

```
ID                                 | ProfileID                      |Supervisor
1aE02B7A-09C7-4955-80D7-0FD1A42abD |D4ABD930-AC52-4F39-B235-0E6CA6C32309|1002
12343-AC52-24349-B235-0E6CAGVCXXCD |6FE02B7A-09C7-4955-80D7-0FD1A42CDD8B|10007
```

I want to update column `SuperVisorID (Hre_Profile) =  s2.supervisor (type ID)`

```
update s1 set s1.SupervisorID = (s2.supervisor) from hre_profile s1 inner join hre_workhistory s2 on s1.id=s2.profileid
select s1.codeemp, s1.supervisorID, s2.supervisor 
from hre_profile s1 
inner join hre_workhistory s2 on s1.id=s2.profileid
```

```
Codeemp |        SupervisorID                       |    supervisor
400287  |     6FE02B7A-09C7-4955-80D7-0FD1A42CDD8B  |     1002
1002    |     ABC12343-AC52-4F39-B235-0E6CAVCXXCDS  |     10007
```

Answer (score 0):

**Third attempt -**
As per your comment below, I have change update statement-

```
update s1
set s1.SupervisorID = s1.ID
from Hre_Profile s1
inner join Hre_WorkHistory s2 on s1.id=s2.profileid and s1.CodeEmp = s2.Supervisor
```

**Second attempt -**
Ok, You are trying to update `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column from `VARCHAR` column.
I think you have to alter `Hre_Profile` table and change datatype of `SupervisorID` column to `VARCHAR(50)`.

```
ALTER TABLE Hre_Profile ALTER COLUMN SupervisorID VARCHAR(50) NULL;
```

**First attempt -**
I think you are looking for correct update statement to update table. Please try below syntax-

```
update s1
set s1.SupervisorID = (s2.supervisor)
from hre_profile s1
inner join hre_workhistory s2 on s1.id=s2.profileid
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote syntax. i want to update like this with many row :  update s1 set s1.SupervisorID = (select id from hre_ profile where codeemp=s2.supervisor) from hre_profile s1 inner join hre_workhistory s2 on s1.id=s2.profileid.